# Parent items in NavigationView don't gray out for disabled state

Tags: android, menu, navigationview

I have NavigationView with menu that has some items with child items. I set them es disabled for start then I am re-enabling them. It looks like visually parent items ignore disabled state, child items works right. Any way to change this so they looks grayed same as their child items ?

```
 <item
    android:enabled="false"
    android:title="@string/right_panel_question_6_nationality">
    <menu android:id="@+id/menu_long_form_nationality">
        <group
            android:id="@+id/menu_long_form_nationality_group"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_long_form_question_18"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:title="Vaša národnosť" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_long_form_question_18.1"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:title="Iná národnosť" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_long_form_question_19"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:title="Materínsky Jazyk" />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

[image]